# Limit of $\mathbb{P}(\sqrt n - 1 \leq \sqrt{X_1^2 + \cdots X_n^2} \leq \sqrt{n} + 1)$ wrt $n$ for standard multivariate normal $X$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $X$ is a standard multivariate normal distribution. Then what is the limit of the $c_n$ where the $c_n$ are $\mathbb{P}(\sqrt n - 1\leq \sqrt{X_1^2 + \cdots X_n^2} \leq \sqrt n + 1)$? I want to say this is a simple application of the CLT, but I'm not sure.

Here's something:

I think the inequality can be simplified as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} - \sqrt 2 \leq \frac{\sum X_i^2 - n}{\sqrt{2n}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + \sqrt 2$$
Since $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]$ = 1 and Variance is $ 2$, we may use the central limit theorem to get that this goes to $\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt 2 \leq Z \leq \sqrt 2)$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and this is a constant. Is this correct?

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4101470/321264.

Comment: On stats.SE, the phrase "$X$ is a ... random variable" followed by mentions of $X_i$ is generally taken to mean that the $X_i$ are _independent_ realizations of $X$. In your premise, $X$ is a _vector_ random variable, and so you should explain what $X_i^2$ means to you. Squaring each component of the random _vector_ $X$? The _scalar_ random variable $X^TX$ or $XX^T$ depending on whether you  like column vectors or row vectors?